# 'Python SyntaxError: invalid syntax' when starting a thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a strange (but probably also silly) problem when using Python threading.

I wrote a simple port scanner in Python and want it to scan many ports asynchronously. However, when I execute the script, SyntaxError is thrown in the second line of this piece of code:

```
t = Thread(target=check_port, args=(target_host, int(target_port))
t.start()
```

How is that possible? I have used that construction before and everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing parentheses:

```
t = Thread(target=check_port, args=(target_host, int(target_port))
#         ^1                       ^2               ^3          ^^?
```

There should be *three* closing `)` parens at the end, you only have two.

Without that missing `)` the logical line hasn't ended yet, and the next physical line is seen as part of the `Thread()` call, but then the syntax is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

`)`  is missing.

There are **three open brackets** and only **two close brackets**. So one closing bracket is missing.

```
t = Thread(target=check_port, args=(target_host, int(target_port)))
```